# Ground Fault Interrupter

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-phase, current-transformer, fault, gfci

I was trying to simulate a circuit where it can detect grounded neutral conditions in the household. I need to have a current transformer which can detect the current differential ans sends a signal to op amp which can further amplify it/convert to voltage. How can i do this?

Comment: "...can detect grounded neutral conditions" where they should be (the panel) or where they shouldn't be (in the appliance)" ?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have a current transformer which can detect the current differential

If both line and neutral are passed through the core of a current transformer, the secondary current of the CT will be proportional to the difference between the two currents. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I tried the way you said. I want to use op amp afterwards how should I add this